# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox in java to convert pdf to images. But when I compile I got the message

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory`.

[Here is the code I am following](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/pdfbox/PDFToImage.java.html). Kindly help me to get out of this error.

Comment: Please show how you're *running* the code. Basically it's a classpath problem, by the sounds of it.

Comment: download and add those jars: [pdfbox.apache.org/download](http://pdfbox.apache.org/download)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need the [Apache Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) library on your classpath.

Chances are that you're missing *all* the [dependencies of PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html):

### Minimum Requirement for PDFBox

- Java 1.5
- commons-logging

Answer (score 10):

Add ***commons-logging.jar*** file to your project classpath. that will fix the issue.

Comment: Your answer is identical to several already existing answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the apache library is on your class path at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Is the commons logging jar on the classpath? You can download this from [Download Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I have tried all of the solutions on the web, I had all of the required JAR files in my CLASSPATH ... but it didn't work. then I decided to move my JAR files from my DROPBOX folder to a normal folder and it worked!

So if your JARs are on dropbox or anything like that, move them to a normal folder and add them to your classpath! it will solve the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception.